# Selenium ChromeDriver unknown error unable to discover open pages

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need help with setting up ChromeDriver in Selenium WebDriver.

I have downloaded the latest version of ChromeDriver and added the path to the exe to my PATH environment variable.

However, when I try to run any scripts they fail on the line

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

An instance of Chrome opens with a black screen and the address set as "data;," and I get a popup stating:

> "Chrome Automation Extension has crashed".

Continuing from that point, I get the following exception details:

> unknown error: unable to discover open pages
>
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>
> Command duration or timeout: 61.19 seconds
>
> Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:03:33'

As I say, I've got the latest version of ChromeDriver and I have checked that Chrome is currently running the latest version so I know it isn't an issue with outdated versions of either.

I'm sure it must be something simple which I'm overlooking, but I just can't think what. Does anyone have any ideas?

**Edit**

Here's the log for the case, where Capability is not passed as a variable:

```
[0.885][INFO]: COMMAND InitSession {
   "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "chromeOptions": {
         "args": [  ],
         "extensions": [  ]
      },
      "platform": "ANY",
      "version": ""
   }
}
[0.886][INFO]: Populating Preferences file: {
   "alternate_error_pages": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "autofill": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "browser": {
      "check_default_browser": false
   },
   "distribution": {
      "import_bookmarks": false,
      "import_history": false,
      "import_search_engine": false,
      "make_chrome_default_for_user": false,
      "show_welcome_page": false,
      "skip_first_run_ui": true
   },
   "dns_prefetching": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "profile": {
      "content_settings": {
         "pattern_pairs": {
            "https://*,*": {
               "media-stream": {
                  "audio": "Default",
                  "video": "Default"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "default_content_setting_values": {
         "geolocation": 1
      },
      "default_content_settings": {
         "geolocation": 1,
         "mouselock": 1,
         "notifications": 1,
         "popups": 1,
         "ppapi-broker": 1
      },
      "password_manager_enabled": false
   },
   "safebrowsing": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "search": {
      "suggest_enabled": false
   },
   "translate": {
      "enabled": false
   }
}
[0.889][INFO]: Populating Local State file: {
   "background_mode": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "ssl": {
      "rev_checking": {   
         "enabled": false
      }
   }
}
[0.936][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Program Files    (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-update --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-logging --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension="C:\Users\Rory\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir10152_5411\internal" --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12607 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\Rory\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir10152_31299" data:,
[61.070][INFO]: RESPONSE InitSession unknown error: unable to discover open pages
```

Comment: Are you running your tests on a remote machine or locally?

Comment: Hi, try setting the chrome exe file as follows
File file = new File("C:\\chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
Capability= DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

Comment: @user2272115, I'm running locally.

Comment: @selva, I tried adding this, but I'm getting the same results.

I'm assuming that the new File should point to the location of the exe, which in my case is at C:\\eclipse\\chromedriver.exe

I'm also assuming that Capability needs to be set as an instance of DesieredCapabilities and then added as a variable to the driver call as:

    driver = new ChromeDriver(Capability);

Comment: @RSCruickshank yes the path is to the exe of chromedriver only. You have to do as following

1st try like this
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");

  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.google.com");

2nd try like this 
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

webDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

Comment: @selva, I've tried both options here. In the both cases it fails and throws an exception on driver = new ChromeDriver(); with or without Capability set as a variable. So in the first case it doesn't actually reach the line driver.get("google.com"); because it throws an exception on the previous line. Exception details are exactly the same as above.

Comment: @RSCruickshank Can you just past the full log.

Comment: @selva, log added as requested.

Comment: Im using this System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Driver/chromedriver.exe");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.get("https://www.google.com");